# Can an npm package specify that npx/npm init should always use the latest version?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx, npm-init

I have a package (let's call it `create-foo`) that my users are supposed to always run using `npm init foo`. The problem is that if the user has previously run the command it never updates it. I know that the user can run `npm init foo@latest` but is there a way to change the default behavior for a package? i.e. is there a way for a package to specify that it wants to always prefer the remote version to be checked?

Comment: Maybe you are talking about npm install and not npm init

Comment: No, [npm init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-init)

Comment: Have you found a way to do it? I am having a similar issue with `npx`. The npm team very unfortunatelly doesn't seem to want the "use latest" behaviour as default (or an option for users and devs to set it). https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2329#issuecomment-826016790

I am thinking of creating another package, and my pkg1 will have a call to npx pkg2@latest. Ugly workaround, but probably will work. Or, at each start, it will check if the current version is the latest one. Else, will delete the current cache and call itself.

Comment: No, I never did find a solution. Your ugly workarounds sound like the best hope.